# Jquery - Conditionally fire blur() based on other elements change()

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have to radio buttons and a textbox. I have a change() on the radio buttons to do some processing. I have a blur on the textbox to do some processing. If I am in textbox and I click one of the radio buttons, I want the blur to fire. If I click the other radio button, I don't want the blur to fire.

Is there a way to see the events that are queued? Meaning the blur() happens before the change() but could I peek ahead to see that a change() is coming?
Is there a way to see why the blur() happened? Meaning where did I click to cause the blur()?

Answer (score 0):

Using the google javascript debugger in console may show you when the events may occur, but if you want to know which one comes firstly, I just know the hard way: Reading the code step by step over the debugger.

Note that the `on()` binding can stack up multiple times if you use it on change without anything to unbind it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to identify these things is by adding a Console.log inside each of these events that identifies it. Then discovering the order is as simple as pressing F12 and looking at the console.

For your issue with wanting to conditionally fire blur events, you can bind/unbind events at will. So just you can have an action that 'unbinds' the blur event form the textbox, and another action that binds it back to it, and figure out when you need it bound/unbound.